# OS X cocoa send HTTP response to PHP page, wait for PHP response to request, Continue

Tags: objective-c, macos

id like to achive what is mentioned in the title, can anyone point me in the right direction regarding ressources or torturials? I do understand the basics of the HTTP protocol, but i am fairly new to OS X programming.

Comment: This is not an IOS Application, but a OSX one

Comment: 1. you send an HTTP _request_; 2. [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

In fact you can use the  NSMutableURLRequest, if you want to make a test to start you can do this:

//test.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface test : NSObject<NSURLConnectionDataDelegate>{
NSMutableData* _responseData;
}
```

//test.m

```
@implementation test

//Just call this method to start the request. 
-(void)testRequest{
 //set request
 NSURL url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ip/file.php"];
 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed
                                                 timeoutInterval:20.0];
 //Start the request 
 NSURLConnection * connection;
 connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest: request delegate:self];
}
```

after this you have to implement all the methods as woz said but catching the response:

```
#pragma mark - NSURLConectionDlegate Methods
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
 _responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

//Receive data from the server
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
// Append the new data to the instance variable

[_responseData appendData:data];
}

- (NSCachedURLResponse *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
              willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse*)cachedResponse {
// Return nil to indicate not necessary to store a cached response for this connection
return nil;
}
 //in this method you can check the response.
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    // The request is complete and data has been received
    NSString *receivedDataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:_responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"this is reponse: %@",receivedDataString);

}
```

server side
    //file.php
       echo "hello";

Answer (score 0):

I like short solutions, and using blocks.

```
- (void)sendRequestWithURL:(NSURL*) url {
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                               if (!error) {
                                   NSLog(@"%@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
                               }
                               else {
                                   ///log error
                               }
                           }];
}
```